# Device from which the email was first opened

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, mobile, email-tracking

Is it possible to know if the email sent for a specific user was opened first from a mobile device?

Comment: Without deeply digging into this: I would say no because no DataView stores DeviceInformation or UserAgents.

Comment: I know there used to be an option inside the tracking extract interaction to 'include device information' or something similar. You might want to reach out to global support and see if they are able to turn this option on for you. It provides a CSV with webagent and device info it gathers via the tracking pixel. As with all this info, it is unreliable, but might provide some insight.

Answer (score 3):

You can get device information but user-wise device information can't be obtained. So, which subscriber opened the email on which device can't be obtained as far as I know but how many subscribers opened or clicked on a particular mobile device or computer/laptop can be obtained from SFMC reports.

[image]

This does not quite answer the question because the report does not specify 'email sent for a specific user' but 'Blank Template for Email sending performance' can be used to get a lot of user tracking information.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, this functionality doesn't exist in SFMC. We use third-party tools to track that.

Comment: Can you tell me which tools you use for this?